# How do I start -testnet in -deprecatedrpc to test a script?

Tags: bitcoind, testnet, bitcoin-cli

I hope all is well during our COVID-19 pandemic.

My question: How do I start "bitcoind -testnet" in "-deprecatedrpc=signtransaction" mode?

Do I simply start it the same way without being a test and insert "-testnet" between "bitcoind" and "deprecatedrpc" like this"bitcoind -testnet -deprecatedrpc=signrawtransaction" (I mean, I need this to make sure my script is tested before running it and it keeps saying "error: Could not connect to the server 127.0.0.1:18332 (error code 1 - "EOF reached").

Thanks.

Comment: Can you point to *where* this identical question has been asked and answered? Also, my question refers to "bitcoin", not the website (?).

Comment: ...I only found where the issue referred to -testnet and the server protocol in general, *not* the use of *-testnet* in *-deprecated* mode. I do hope this clears up the understanding of my question. Have a nice day.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick's comment was about your corollary question whether you may offer a contest to incentive answers to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to start `-testnet` in deprecated mode to test my script like this:

```
bitcoind -testnet -deprecatedrpc=signrawtransaction
```